# how to get the value of an input field by simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to get the value of a input field. For eg. i have this input field in my HTML. Now i have used this for getting the HTML DOM.

simple_html_dom.php

After that i tried like this. But cant get the value.

```
  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
  $file_token = str_get_html($response);
  $tokenid = $file_token->find('input#hash_9e879c117c');
  echo $tokenid->value;
```

I tried this and got the value.

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($response);
  $token = $doc->getElementById("hash_9e879c117c")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;
```

But here is the HTML is display which i dont want to display the all HTML. I want only to get the value.

```
<input name="hash_9e879c117c" id="hash_9e879c117c" value="692ad23ba417d18d132897584fdaa042ff66d421" type="hidden">
```

Can you let me know how to get the value from the above input field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [DOMElement::getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/domelement.getattribute.php)?

```
$token = $doc->getElementById("hash_9e879c117c")->getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: I have tried it already. But you did not read what i am asking. I am asing about simple_html_dom.php. Is that same thing possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
$tokenid = $file_token->find('input#hash_9e879c117c', 0);
```

This gives the first element rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
include "./simple_html_dom.php" ;
$html = file_get_html("https://example.com/login") ; 
$token = $html->getElementByTagName("input[name=_token]")->getAttribute("value") ; 
echo "token is : " $token ;
```

Comment: Raid Hamel, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.